# pgfplots: Grid Lines below Filling

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

I want to fill the area between two curves and have the grid lines below the filling. Is this possible?

(From [Showing grid on top of plot fill with PGFplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125823/showing-grid-on-top-of-plot-fill-with-pgfplots) I thought `axis on bottom` might work, but this seems not to be a command.)

Edit: The filling method is the one suggested in [Fill the area between two curves calculated by pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/fill-the-area-between-two-curves-calculated-by-pgfplots) by Christian Feuersanger, and requires a recent version of `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = middle,
    smooth,
    no markers,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    minor tick num =1,
    grid=both,
    domain=0:2,]
        \addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=200,name path=A,black] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot+[domain=0:1,name path=B,black] {x};
        \addplot[blue!50] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @A.Ellett Do you have the newest version of `pgfplots`? I had to update it to use the filling method Christian Feuersanger recommended in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/fill-the-area-between-two-curves-calculated-by-pgfplots.

Comment: @A.Ellett it works fine for me

Comment: @A.Ellett I follow the steps given in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: @cmhughes It seems to be an issue with my current version of `pgf`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you add `set layers` option the axis environment, it sets a hierarchricrhchaheal(!?) order as the `standard`  layer order, namely `axis background, axis grid, axis ticks, axis lines, axis tick labels, main, axis descriptions, axis foreground`. This simply switches the order of drawing order. Hence it is feature not a bug. Otherwise you can reorder the layers as a customized layer style

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[set layers,
    axis lines = middle,
    smooth,
    no markers,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    minor tick num =1,
    grid=both,
    domain=0:2,]
        \addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=200,name path=A,black] {sqrt(x)};
        \addplot+[domain=0:1,name path=B,black] {x};
        \addplot[blue!50] fill between[of=A and B];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

percusse's answer is correct.

What beats me is that `pgfplots` should have done that automatically as soon as it encounters a `fill between` plot.

Consequently, there is a second answer:

---

This is a bug and will be fixed in the next version of pgfplots (probably `1.11` once it is ready).

Comment: Using this a bit more: percusse's answer puts the filling on top of gridlines and on top of tick labels (1, 2, 3, etc). I think ideally  the filling should go above grid lines but under tick labels. I am not sure how uniform that opinion is, though.

Comment: @mrc I see. Pgfplots comes with two presets, the one shown by percusse and `axis on top` which puts both grid and tick labels on top. Perhaps your is better, I do not know.